# The response has five or fewer unique values. Are you sure you want to do regression?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I am using random forest to predict review rating (numeric variable with values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5). When running the code I get this warning:

```
The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

I have no option to ignore the warning and run the model as a regression. I have tried writing "Yes" "y" "1" but nothing works. I do not want to do classification by changing the variable to a factor... or do you think I should? Is there a way to overcome this warning?

Thanks

Comment: You actually should change to a factor. Using a regression will also give you predictions like 2.3725, which is not a valid value on your scale. So change it to a classification task.

Comment: @deschen many review websites have a scale of 1-5 stars for leaving reviews, but report the mean score, such as 4.35. This is valid for some applications, but certainly a bit of context would definitely help here. Adrianna, it would help us to help you if you included some actual code and data in your question. At the moment, this question is bordering on off-topic as it is more about stats than programming.

Comment: @AllanCameron Assuming that a score of 4.35 is valid for my application and focusing on the programming part and not the stats behind it, is there a way to overcome the warning message as to perform regression and not classification?

Comment: You should be able to pass the warning following the instructions in your console. IIRC, you indeed have to type in a 1 or so and then confirm by hitting Enter.

Comment: @AllanCameron reporting a mean is something different than predicting a value no user can provide. E.g. in your website review example, if users can only provide discrete values, the RF model should follow this structural requirement. You can still report the mean of that. But agree, probably depends on the context and is not answering TO‘s question.